# send message via chatwoot api - String does not have #dig method

Tags: php, chatwoot

I would like send an interactive message via php and chatwoot api.
https://www.chatwoot.com/developers/api/#tag/Messages/operation/create-a-new-message-in-a-conversation

interactive message like type 1:
https://www.chatwoot.com/docs/product/others/interactive-messages/#1-options

my php code:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://mydomain.de/api/v1/accounts/1/conversations/19/messages");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
    array(
            "content"               =>  "Hi",
            "message_type"          =>  "outgoing",
            "content_type"          =>  "input_select",
            "content_attributes"    =>  '{"items": [{ "title": "Option1", "value": "Option 1" }, { "title": "Option2", "value": "Option 2" }]}',
            "private"               =>  false
    )
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array (
        'api_access_token: XXX' 
    ),
);


$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Response**

```
Array
(
    [error] => String does not have #dig method
)
```

I can send simple messages without problems. but this message I get when I tried to send interactive messages. where is my mistake?

Comment: Looks like something that is supposed to be a hash is being interpreted as a String. Can you verify if you are using the right syntax to pass the content_attributes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using the unofficial typescript SDK -> "@figuro/chatwoot-sdk".

I did the same with Axios and it worked.

```
const response = await axios.post('https://HOST/api/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/conversations/CONVERSATION_ID/messages', 
{
"content": "Select one of the items below",
"content_type": "input_select",
"content_attributes": {
    "items": [
        { "title": "Option1", "value": "Option 1" },
        { "title": "Option2", "value": "Option 2" }
    ]
},
"private":false
}, 
{
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'api_access_token': 'YOUR TOKEN'
  }
});
```

Sorry, I know you work in PHP. I assume your library does the parsing wrong. Try using another PHP library for sending the POST request.